# If the following code executes, which value is assigned to strA?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find which value is assigned to strA?

```
Dim dbleTest as Double = 0.25
Dim strA as String = dblTest.ToString("p")
```

Comment: use the debugger and find out?

Comment: 0.00% because dbleTest <> dblTest :-)

Comment: If your question is simply "what happens if I do XYZ" why don't you just **TRY FOR YOURSELF** and find out?

Answer (score 4):

If you correct your typo, and use `Dim dlbTest As Double = 0.25`, then this prints `25.00 %` (locale specific, some locales may have different decimal separators).

Without that in place, the result will depend on the [Option Explicit checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) currently in place in the file, and potentially the value assigned to `dblTest` (if it exists in scope).

Comment: And depends also on locale settings (mine is 25,00%)

Comment: @Steve Good point - edited to include that info.